# Can ssh (agent) work with two separate identities?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-agent, github

I use an Ubuntu 14.10 distribution, and two private keys, one encrypted (`~/.ssh/E.key`), and one not encrypted (`~/.ssh/NE.key`), which I use for accessing two github repositories, respectively, `repoE` and `repoNE`.

I use the common trick of aliasing `gitbhub.com` to two different domains, which are mapped to the respective ssh keys.

Content (only relevant) of `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com-E
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/E.key

Host github.com-NE
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/NE.key
```

Content (only relevant) of local repository configurations:

```
# /path/to/repoE/.git/config:

[remote "origin"]
  url = git@github.com-E:organizationE/repoE.git

# /path/to/repoNE/.git/config:

[remote "origin"]
  url = git@github.com-NE:organizationNE/repoNE.git
```

I use `ssh-add`, so that I don't need to type the passphrase for any access to `repoE`.

The problem is that apparently, only the first key I add is used (I can see the offer from the ssh client log).

This is for example a sample run:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/E.key

# I can now access repoE, but not repoNE

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/NE.key

# Still the same (I can access repoE, but not repoNE)

$ ssh-add -D

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/NE.key

# I can now access repoNE, but not repoE

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/E.key

# Still the same (I can access repoNE, but not repoE)
```

Comment: Are you using the same ssh username for the two keys?

Comment: I've tried the debug log, and what happens is that the ssh-agent only offers the first key added; not clear why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

`gpg-agent` and most probably `ssh-agent`, too, doesn't care what the keys belong to. The keys are identified by their keygrip (the fingerprint of the pure key material whereas e.g. an OpenPGP fingerprint is over the key material and some additional data like the creation date).

You can enable / increase the logging in the config file `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`. Relevant options are

- `--debug-level`
- `--log-file`

To activate this change `gpg-agent` either needs a `SIGHUP` (for changes of certain already given options, see the "SIGHUP" section in the man page) or must be restarted.

You may also enable logging in the `ssh` config file to see what exactly `git push` does with `ssh`. `strace -f -e trace=execve git push` might help, too. Relevant options are:

- `log_file`
- `LogLevel`

Comment: I've tried the debug log, and what happens is that the ssh-agent only offers the first key added (so that only one of the two works at a time); not clear why this happens.